# GREP Phone number from CSV + Next field (Name field)

Tags: grep

So I am looking to grep out the phone number and name field from my CSV. file. Now this is what I'm currently trying to do:

```
grep '\(([0-9]\{3\})\|[0-9]\{3\}\)[ -]\?[0-9]\{3\}[ -]\?[0-9]\{4\}' file
```

Here's what the CSV file looks like:

```
2124605053;travellobby;info@travellobby.in;91;8126681266;TRAVEL LOBBY (INDIA);Flights | Hotels | Holidays | Cruises | Travel Insurance | VisaTag @travellobby or #travellobby for a feature.Facebook | Twitter  TravelLobby;309;149;140;http://www.travellobby.in/;Travel Company;73, Shopping Complex, Sector 7, Urban Estate;132001;29.69;76.988333333333
```

Now, the fields I want is the phone number and the name field (which is next to the phone number field to the right).

I am essentially trying to grep this information: `8126681266,TRAVEL LOBBY (INDIA)`

Also: Is there away to search for a string/character, i.e. `8126681266` (The phone number) and grab the field next to it (The name field) and output, `8126681266, TRAVEL LOBBY (INDIA)`?

Comment: Why don't you use [tag:awk] for this?

Comment: @oguzismail I'm not opposed to that, but I'm clueless with it. Could you show me an example, please?

Comment: I could, but your regexp matches first field too, do you want all matching fields + fields adjacent to them?

Comment: @oguzismail Ah, true. In that case what about if we were to do this instead?

Comment: Is there away to search for a string/character, i.e. 8126681266 (The phone number) and grab the field next to it (The name field) and output, 8126681266, TRAVEL LOBBY (INDIA)? @oguzismail

Comment: `awk -F';' -v OFS=',' '{for(i=1;i<NF;++i){if($i~/(([0-9]{3})|[0-9]{3})[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[ -]{0,1}[0-9]{4}/){print $i,$(++i)}}}' file`

Comment: Yes, it's easier than matching a field with regex. E.g: `awk -F';' -v OFS=',' -v q='8126681266' '{for(i=1;i<NF;++i){if($i==q){print q,$(i+1);break}}}' file`

Comment: @oguzismail Ah thanks, let me test it out!